# Error sending email using ansible via sendgrid

Tags: email, ansible, continuous-integration, sendgrid

Through the ansible documentation page, I see ansible supporting sending email via sendgrid. I have tried following the code example but I still failed to send and exit the following message.

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [sendgrid] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "parameters are mutually exclusive: api_key, username"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/valutac/opreker/mail-test.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Here I also display the contents of the playbook

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   tasks:
     - sendgrid:
          username: "mail"
          password: "xxx"
          api_key: "SG.1414rfdsvefvwev.dsadasvef34r2-3e1qdqecweqc"
          from_address: "ansible@mycompany.com"
          to_addresses:
            - "ops@mycompany.com"
          subject: "Deployment success."
          body: "The most recent Ansible deployment was successful."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error msg is clear:

> parameters are mutually exclusive: api_key, username

[Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sendgrid_module.html) explains:

> username for logging into the SendGrid account.
>   Since 2.2 it is only required if api_key is not supplied.

Comment: problem solved, thank you.
Previously I misunderstood the ansible documentation so I entered my username, password, and api_key.